# Pass option arguments to Spark dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a Spark Session in my Scala code the following way:

```
       sparkContext.getSparkSession()
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.prop1","true")
      .option("kafka.prop2", "1")
      .option("kafka.prop3", "ddd")
      .option("kafka.prop4", "rttr")
      .load()
      .writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation)
      .foreachBatch(forEachFunction.arceusForEachFunction(_,_))
      .start()
```

I want to remove the hard codings in the code and want to make it generic. I have a config with all the parameters and can create a `Map` with the key value pairs for the `.option` fields.
But I am not sure how to create the .option parameters when sending to Spark

What I intend is e.g.

```
Map("kafka.prop1" --> "true"),
("kafka.prop2" --> "SASL_SSL")
```

and then use this to populate the option. But I not sure how to pass this to the .option.
Also, any other better way is also welcome.

Comment: Isn't it just `val myOptions = Map(???)` and then `.readStrem.options(myOptions)`?

Comment: I am not sure. I will try and see it that works. Thanks

Comment: Wondering how this can work for value types that aren't only Strings